# North Cyprus tourist visa for a travel document passport holder

Tags: visas, turkey, cyprus, palestine

Hey people I need your help with some information. I’m a Palestinian. I have a travel document which is a Palestinian Egyptian passport. I live in Abu Dhabi, UAE.

I’m planning to visit my freind in north Cyprus. He’s a student. I asked the representative office of north Cyprus in UAE. They asked me for

- a 6 months valid passport
- round trip flight ticket
- and a hotel recommendation

Because I will stay with my friend, they asked for an invitation from my friend, his university enrollment confirmation and his bank statement. They will give me a paper or apparently a stamp which I'll show at Ercan International airport.

So what I want to know is whether I will be able to enter north Cyprus or my visit might be rejected at Ercan International airport because of the passport I’m holding. I’m afraid that all of my money might go to waste even though I have all the papers ready and sorted. I would appreciate advice from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for North Cyprus are presumably the same as for Turkey, which is that Palestinian citizens [need a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Palestinian_citizens) in advance. The NTTC office in the UAE has your passport; they know what type it is. If they issue a visa (whether in the passport or on a detached sheet) you will be good to go. It's *possible* you could be refused entry on arrival at Ercan, which can happen on any visa. Whether they issue the visa is, of course, up to them.

Assuming you are connecting in Istanbul, there is a transit lounge airside which is apparently open to all without need of a transit visa.

Comment: The thing is there is no nothern Cyprus embassy here in UAE only a representative office and they told me they will  detach a paper on my passport and in ercan airport they will see it and let me enter but I don’t know for some reason I’m worried cause of my rank of passport or anything and yes I’ll need to stop by Istanbul for transit to get to North Cyprus and yes thank you for your time sir